# windows 7 roaming profiles in server 2003?

Tags: windows-7

My boss is trying to upgrade to win7 for users but leave our server 2003 alone. I'm trying to test with setting up a test user machine in win7 and no matter how I change settings, I cannot get the local pc to load the roaming profile. It sees the network drives and requires the password set in active directory on the domain controller, but it will not link to the roaming profile. I've tried the .v2 extension on the profile and in the profile path with no luck. 
Is there a tutorial somewhere for settings that will allow this to work?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this should work out of the box. Do notice that a windows 7 profile is not compatible with a windows XP profile, which is why it automatically makes a .v2. So if you're trying to use an XP profile on a windows 7 pc, it will simply not load.

On top of that, profiles work differently in windows 7 than XP as such that there's a registry key involved too. If you made an error here, by just copy a profile to the Users directory, it will by default fail to load a profile even if it were to be correct.

To manage profiles on a windows 7 machine, do the following:

1. Go to `Startmenu`
2. Right click `Computer`
3. Choose `Properties`
4. On the left, choose `Advanced System Settings`
5. Click the <kbd>Settings...</kbd> button under the `User Profiles` group.
6. Any error will be visible here. You can delete profiles here as well.
7. Delete the profile that gives trouble, then restart the computer and login using the domain credentials. The pc will then download a working profile from the server.